# POST request doesn't recognize in my controller using Opencart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart, opencart2.x

I have a problem in my code. In my setup I created a single page for language selection. And I copy some of opencart's code on language template and also on controller. But my problem is after passing my form, the action controller doesn't get any POST data from my form.

```
<form action="{{ action }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-language">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="border_index_in">
            <div class="holder">
                <h3>ENGLISH</h3>
                <button class="language-select btn btn-green" type="button" name="en-gb">Choose</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="border_index_in">
            <div class="holder">
                <h3>日本語</h3>
                <button class="language-select btn btn-green" type="button" name="jap">選択</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="border_index_in">
            <div class="holder">
                <h3>中文</h3>
                <button class="language-select btn btn-green" type="button" name="zh-hk">选择</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
  // Language
    $('#form-language .language-select').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#form-language input[name=\'code\']').val($(this).attr('name'));
        $('#form-language').submit();
    });
```

**Controller to show my language selection page**

```
public function language_switch() {
    $this->load->model('setting/extension');
    $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_meta_title'));
    $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
    $this->document->setKeywords($this->config->get('config_meta_keyword'));

    if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
        $this->document->addLink($this->config->get('config_url'), 'canonical');
    }

    $data['action'] = $this->url->link('common/language/language');
    $data['code'] = $this->session->data['language'];

    $styles_array = array(
        'catalog/view/theme/onemidorie/stylesheet/style.css'
    );

    $scripts_array = array(

    );

    foreach($styles_array as $st) {
        $this->document->addStyle($st);
    }

    foreach($scripts_array as $sc) {
        $this->document->addScript($sc);
    }

    $data['styles'] = $this->document->getStyles();
    $data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts();

    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/language_selection', $data));

}
```

**Controller that should accept the POST data from my form:**

```
public function language() {
        print_r($this->request->post['code']); //Notice: Undefined index: code 
        die;
        if (isset($this->request->post['code'])) {
            $this->session->data['language'] = $this->request->post['code'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['redirect'])) {
            $this->response->redirect($this->request->post['redirect']);
        } else {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('common/home'));
        }
    }
```

Can you help me this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
print_r($this->request->post); 
        die;

Then you will get some post data.

because you define the name like "en-gb","jap" and "zh-hk". So please use above code then you can get solution.

Comment: If I do that the output is an empty array :(

Comment: Kindly share your information or communicate on skype: jks0586 for this issue. I will resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're not posting any data - you're just showing a button.  Use something more like

```
<input type="submit" value="english" name="lang"/>
<input type="submit" value="japanese" name="lang"/>
```

etc. then just look at

```
$_POST['lang']
```

and see if it's english, japanese or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how opencart set language in /catalog/controller/startup/startup.php:

```
// Overwrite the default language object
$language = new Language($code);
$language->load($code);

$this->registry->set('language', $language);
```

So in controller what should accept the POST data you should dublicate this code before loading language:

```
// $this->request->post['code'] = 'en-gb' or 'ru-ru' or whatever.

$language = new Language($this->request->post['code']);
$language->load($this->request->post['code']);
$this->registry->set('language', $language);

// now opencart use new language and you can use it too:

$this->load->language('common/header');
$text_home = $this->language->get('text_home');
```

This works for me in opencart 2